# Can I get the orientation matrix in real time?

Tags: python, add-on, vector, matrix

I need to calculate the normal orientation matrix for the tool. There is a way to get a custom orientation matrix

```
bpy.context.scene.transform_orientation_slots[0].custom_orientation.matrix.to_4x4()
```

Is there a similar method for getting any orientation matrix ? (GLOBAL, LOCAL, NORMAL, GIMBAL, VIEW, CURSOR)

I will say in advance that I am not satisfied with creating a custom orientation, since I need to get a realtime matrix

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "real time" in this context?

Comment: @RobertGützkow I need a matrix for gizmo, so I can't execute statements from the draw_prepare function in gizmogroup.

Comment: @RobertGützkow For example, I know how to get a normal matrix by executing a regular operator, using: bpy.context.window.scene.transform_orientation_slots[0].type = 'NORMAL'
bpy.ops.transform.create_orientation(name=name, use=True, overwrite=True)
user_matrix=bpy.context.scene.transform_orientation_slots[0].custom_orientation.matrix.to_4x4()                                                                                                 
But this is not suitable for gizmo